# Get number of children a game object has via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Title says it all: What is the best way to find out how many children a `gameObject` has via script.

Comment: You might want to provide some code. What have you tried so far and what is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: `foreach (Transform child in transform)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 1**:

A simple variable [`transform.hierarchyCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hierarchyCount.html), has been added to *Unity 5.4* and above. This should simplify this.

**OLD answer for Unity 5.3 and Below**:

`transform.childCount` provided by [Adrea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40993791/3785314) is usually the way to do this but it does not return a child under the child. It only returns a child that is directly under the GameObject `transform.childCount` is been called on. That's it.

To return **all** the child GameObjects, whether under the child of another child which is under another child then you have to do some more work.

The function below can count child:

```
public int getChildren(GameObject obj)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < obj.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        count++;
        counter(obj.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject, ref count);
    }
    return count;
}

private void counter(GameObject currentObj, ref int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < currentObj.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        count++;
        counter(currentObj.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject, ref count);
    }
}
```

Let's say below is what your hierarchy looks like:

[image]

With a simple test script:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Child Count: " + transform.childCount);
    int childs = getChildren(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Child Count Custom: " + childs);
}
```

This is the result between `transform.childCount` and the custom function:

> Child Count: 2
>
> Child Count Custom: 9

As, you can see the `transform.childCount` will not count childs of child but only child of the transform. The custom function was able to count **all** the child GameObjects.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, +1. I edit my answer to specify that.

Comment: @Andrea  Nice. I really can't tell if OP wants to check for the first level or all the child but I do believe that Unity needs to clarify this in their doc.

Comment: A part of what others have commented, it's important to note that `hierarchyCount` has a fixed value all the time, while `childCount` actually counts only the current children. In case your GameObject is dynamic (new elements apear or are destroyed), the former will always return the same value, while `childCount` will change.

Answer (score 4):

You can access its Transform and use [transform.childCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html).

Update: this method works for retrieving all children at the first level. If you want to retrieve the children in the overall hierarchy (also at the deeper levels), follow Programmer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the code bellow!

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!a)
    {
       foreach (Transform child in obj.transform)
       {
           count++; // count - Child object count reference
           if (count >= obj.transform.childCount)
           {
              a = true;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this should count every child of a GameObject!
It will pause the counter when it hits the total amount of child GameObjects using the boolean, "a".