# GameObject doesnt allow more than one child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I am trying to add a bunch of children to a GameObject. The parent GameObject is called `SnakeHead` while all the other GameObjects are called `SnakeBodyParts`

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject snakeHead;
    public GameObject snakeBodyPart;
    public List<GameObject> snakeBodyParts;

    void Start() {
        snakeBodyParts = new List<GameObject>();
        Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeHead);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var newObj = Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeBodyPart);
            newObj.transform.position = new Vector3(snakeHead.transform.position.x, snakeHead.transform.position.y - (i + 1), 0);
            newObj.transform.SetParent(snakeHead.transform);
            snakeBodyParts.Add(newObj);
        }
    }
}
```

So it looke like `snakeHead.transform.childCount;` is 1. Can anyone explain to me this kind of behaviour?
Both `SnakeHead` and `SnakeBodyPart` are a simple Sphere added as a 3D Object to my project.

Comment: When you run this in the debugger and pause, can you see the other children in the editor?

Comment: can you show where you are calling for the `.childcount`

Comment: @SandyGifford Besides SnakeHead I see 5 other GameObjects (original of SnakeBodyPart and 4 clones). So what is weird is that the original of snakeBodyParts are a child of SnakeHead, while all the clones I instantiate in this for-loop arent.

Comment: @ryemoss Right after the for-loop.

Comment: It looks like you're using snakeHead as an instantiable prefab, but never saving a reference to it after instantiating (`Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeHead);`).  Do you set snakeHead in the editor with a prefab from your library?  Or with an object in the game world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that *snakeHead* and *snakeBodyPart* are both prefabs.

The problem is that you are setting the parent of the *snakeBodyPart* with the snakeHead prefab instead of the instantiated *snakeHead*.

When you instantiate *snakeHead*, you are supposed to store it to a temporary variable the use it to set the parent of each instantiated snakeBodyPart(`newObj`).

`Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeHead)` should be `GameObject snakeHaedObj = Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeHead);` then you can do `snakeHaedObj .transform.childCount;` later on to check the count and set the parent of each  *snakeBodyPart* with `newObj.transform.SetParent(snakeHaedObj.transform);`.

Something like this:

```
public GameObject snakeHead;
public GameObject snakeBodyPart;
public List<GameObject> snakeBodyParts;

GameObject snakeHaedObj;

void Start()
{
    snakeBodyParts = new List<GameObject>();
    snakeHaedObj = Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeHead);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var newObj = Instantiate<GameObject>(snakeBodyPart);
        newObj.transform.position = new Vector3(snakeHead.transform.position.x, snakeHead.transform.position.y - (i + 1), 0);
        newObj.transform.SetParent(snakeHaedObj.transform);
        snakeBodyParts.Add(newObj);
    }
}
```

Note that `childCount` will only return the direct child not but not Objects under the child. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40994551/3785314) post for how to do that.