# unity error: Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create dynamically ui button,

I have one prefab,

here is code:

```
  public class SFSConnect : MonoBehaviour {
        SmartFox sfs;

        public GameObject cnv1;
        public GameObject potchPrf;
        public Canvas fCanvas;
    void Start () {
    fCanvas = cnv1.GetComponent<Canvas> ();

            Button ptf1 = potchPrf.GetComponent<Button> ();

            Instantiate(ptf1,new Vector3 (0, 0, 10), Quaternion.identity);


            potchPrf.transform.SetParent (fCanvas.transform);
    }

}
```

I tried thousands of posts, but nothing happened

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is likely from `potchPrf.transform.SetParent (fCanvas.transform);` and this means that you are trying to modify a prefab. You can't change the parent of a prefab from code.

Maybe you wanted to set the parent of the instantied object?

If that's the case then store it in a variable

```
GameObject uiObj = Instantiate<GameObject>(ptf1,new Vector3 (0, 0, 10), Quaternion.identity);
uiObj.transform.SetParent (fCanvas.transform);
```

Also, don't attempt to make a prefab a parent of a GameObject. You run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060409/3785314) problem. Both the GameObject you want to set as a parent and the target(child) GameObject should never be a prefab.

---

If your UI is not complicated, I would totally avoid doing this and just use the `DefaultControls` to create UI dynamically. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194515/unity-create-ui-control-from-script/41219377#41219377) post with so many examples on how to use `DefaultControls` to create UI controls.

Comment: Thanks! I use `DefaultControls` it worked!. So how to change width and height of uiButton?

Comment: You mean the position of the UI object?

Comment: No, change the scale of the UiObject

Comment: `RectTransform.sizeDelta` is used to resize a UI in the x,y axis.

Comment: 4 some reason this isn't valid in my case. I'm trying to modify the object parent to something that lies in Prefebs. (Can I do that?). Or should I ask another question (If it is different from this situation?)

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem I think you will need to provide a screenshot of where the object is and the Hierarchy and where the object prefab it is referencing points to. This means creating a new question.